# Finding escape character in files

Tags: string, powershell, design-patterns, escaping

I'm trying to find the carriage return (`\r`) and new line (`\n`) in files but the following two statements return nothing:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "\r" | group path | select name
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "\n" | group path | select name
```

However, the tab (`\t`) escape character seems to work:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "\t" | group path | select name
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Select-String` operates on *individual lines* of input files by default, and since those lines do not contain the newline sequence at their end, it cannot be matched.
In other words: newline sequences (line breaks) have by default been *stripped* by the time the specified regex (`-Pattern`) is matched against each input line.

You must therefore read each input file *as a whole* in order to match its newline sequences, which `Get-Content -Raw` (PSv3+) allows you to do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object { 
  if (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName | Select-String -Quiet '\r') { $_.Name }
}
```

`Select-String -Quiet` stops at the 1st match, if any, and returns a *Boolean* indicating whether a match was found or not.

Note the need to pass `$_.FullName` rather than just `$_` to `Get-Content -Raw` to ensure that files that aren't in the current directory are properly processed too.
The reason is that `$_`, despite being an *object* that carries full path information, is bound as a *string* to `Get-Content`'s `-Path` parameter, and that string is the mere file *name*, without path information.
This is a [known pitfall](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3772).

Answer (score 0):

short version :

```
gci -file -rec | ? { (gc $_.FullName -Raw) -match "\n"}
```